# Ternary in associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php

How do I do something like this with associative arrays in PHP.

```
array(
    'title' => 'HelloWorld',
    if $user == admin:
      'access callback' => 'callbackHello',
      'access arguments' => array('arg1', 'arg2'),
    if $user != admin:
      'access callback' => 'callbackWorld',
      'access arguments' => array('arg1', 'arg2'),
  );
```

Comment: Does that mean you want a pseudo answer?

Comment: `'access callback' => $user == admin ? 'callbackHello' : 'callbackWorld',`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ternary operators you could do

```
$arr =array(
    'title' => 'HelloWorld',
    'access callback' => $user == 'admin' ? 'callbackHello' : 'callbackWorld',
    'access arguments' => $user == 'admin' ? array('arg1', 'arg2') : array('arg3', 'arg4')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't. Put the logic outside of the array declaration.

```
$arr = ['title' => 'foo'];
if( $user == 'admin' ) {
  $arr['callback'] = 'myCallback1';
  $arr['args'] = [1, 2]
} else {
  $arr['callback'] = 'myCallback2';
  $arr['args'] = [3, 4]
}
```

Ternaries make your code difficult to read and maintain and should be avoided when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Break it up in pieces.

```
$arr =array(
    'title' => 'HelloWorld');
if ($user == "admin"){
     $arr[] = ['access callback' => 'callbackHello',
      'access arguments' => array('arg1', 'arg2')];
}else{
     $arr[] = ['access callback' => 'callbackWorld',
      'access arguments' => array('arg1', 'arg2')];
}
```

---

Non multidimensional array method.
Use array_merge to merge the array with the previous $arr.

```
$arr =array(
    'title' => 'HelloWorld');
if ($user == "admin"){
     $arr = array_merge($arr,['access callback' => 'callbackHello',
      'access arguments' => array('arg1', 'arg2')]);
}else{
     $arr = array_merge($arr,['access callback' => 'callbackWorld',
      'access arguments' => array('arg1', 'arg2')]);
}
```

Comment: I didn't DV, but I guess it's because you create a multidimensional array

Comment: OP has not specified what the output should be. But sure. I'll give a non multidimensional answer too.